# Get ids from related model laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a many to many relationship set between two objects `Tag` and `Post`.
Now, I have to check wich tags that post have in a checkbox list, like so:

```
//Load all possible tags in the controller
//and send it to view
$allTags = \App\Tag::all();
return view('post.edit')->with('allTags');
```

In the view:

```
@foreach($allTags as $tag)
    <input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="{{ $tag->id }}"/>
    {{ $tag->description }}
@endforeach
```

Now, when the user reloads the page, I have to check those checkboxes.

My question is:

This certainly work, but seems like *overkill* to me

```
$relatedTags = [];
foreach($post->tags as $tag){
    $relatedTags[]= $tag->id;
}
```

Is there a way to get only the ids without loading all those objects?

Something like: `$relatedTags = $post->tags()->ids` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with querying the results like that:

```
$relatedTagIds = $post->tags()->select('id')->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

That's how you get clear list of tags ids.

Answer (score 2):

Use this it will fetch only id and description that you need.

```
$allTags = DB::table('tags')->lists('description', 'id');
```

Comment: Good, but in my case I need only the post tags. Not all of them

Comment: what do you mean by post tags?

Comment: I meant only the tags that belong to the post

Comment: @CarlosCarucce You can use `lists` with your relationship: `$relatedTagIds = $post->tags()->lists("id");`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Filip's answer, I found another possible solution.

```
$post->tags->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

I hope someone find it useful

Comment: Worked well in v-6